# Is there a way to approximately convert a standard deviation of log returns to a standard deviation of simple returns?

Tags: standard-deviation, lognormal-distribution, approximation

If I have a standard deviation of log returns, what do I need to know to convert it to a standard deviation of simple returns?

I have got the following R functions which seem to give consistent results for 2 different symmetric distributions.

```
getSDapproxNorm = function(sig, mu){
  rs = rnorm(n = 100000, mean = mu, sd = sig)
  sd(exp(rs) - 1) 
}

getSDapproxT = function(sig, mu){
  rs = rt(n = 100000, df = 10)*sig/(sqrt(10/8)) + mu
  sd(exp(rs) - 1) 
}

doplot = function(mu){
  sds = seq(0.01, 0.2, by = 0.01)

  vals = NULL
  for (s in sds){
    a = getSDapproxNorm(s, mu)
    b = getSDapproxT(s,mu)
    vals = rbind(vals, c(a,b))
  }
  plot(x = sds, y = vals[,1], main = "", xlab = "input", ylab = "output", type = "n")
  grid()
  lines(x = sds, y = vals[,1], col = "black")
  lines(x = sds, y = vals[,2], col = "red")

  legend(x = "topleft",legend = c("norm","r"), col = c("black","red"), lty = 1)
}

doplot(0)
doplot(0.05)
doplot(0.1)
doplot(0.2)
doplot(0.4)
```

Is it safe to use one of these functions to approximate the conversion, if all I know is the mean and the standard deviation?

EDIT: description of R functions

The R functions simulate a bunch of random log returns from a specific distribution such that the resulting series has the required mean and standard deviation. It then converts each log return to a simple return and measures the standard deviation of the simple returns. getSDapproxNorm models log returns as normally distributed which would make the corresponding simple returns log-normally distributed. getSDapproxT models the log returns as T distributed with degrees of freedom equal to 10.

Comment: Can you add an explanation of the R functions in words+equations

Comment: @JuhoKokkala: I have added it in words, not sure if equations would add any insight though.